# Experimental Design in A/B Tests

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, experiment-design, random-allocation

I want to A/B test two separate back-end recommendation logic (A and B) but I'm not sure which method works best (from a statistical standpoint). Here's how my application works:

1. User goes to my application.
2. Application recommends 5 widgets to purchase (using either Logic A or Logic B)
3. User can choose to either buy or not buy.
4. User can use this application over and over again.

I narrowed down to 2 methods of A/B testing.

- The first method is to randomly divide the users up into bucket A and bucket B. Bucket A will contain Logic A and bucket B will contain Logic B. **Example:** If Bob gets bucketed to Bucket A then Bob will always get Logic A.
- The second method is to randomly serve up Logic A 50% of the time and Logic B 50% of the time to the users. **Example:** Bob could get Logic A the first time he visits the application. But then he could just as well get Logic B the second/third/fourth time he visits the application.

In both cases, I can keep track of which logic the user books or doesn't book from. Is method 1 or 2 better to see which logic works best?

Comment: I think this is hard to answer without knowing more about your users.  If it were me I'd pick the second method.  Perhaps one method works better at certain times of day but not at other times.  If you confound user with logic, it will be harder to discern this effect.  Perhaps some users use the recommendation engine 50 times in a row before the next user comes along; then the first method will just bias results, at least until much larger sample sizes are achieved.  In the first method you also have to randomly partition users, which can be hard to do.